# When running with WebDriver, does the Firebug netExport HAR generation utility only capture traffic upon page loads?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, har, netexport

We're leveraging `Firebug` and `NetExport` to capture `HAR` files, while running our `Selenium` automated scripts. 
However, it appears that the `HAR` files are only generated upon a page load, and not when other actions are performed on the page.

In our application, actions performed on the page result in the generation of frames, but seems like the HAR is just captured upon the initial page load, and not the subsequent frames.

Is there any way to capture ALL network traffic, even upon clicks generating frames?